# How to hold SVGs small in pure HTML view?

Tags: html, svg, responsive-design, adaptive-design

When I view a html page with SVG files without CSS, embedded SVGs are expanded to the full viewport of browser, too big. Is it a way to hold SVG small in HTML view?

Maybe only

```
 <svg width="50" height="50">
```

?

Comment: You do this, but it's general better to do this with CSS: `svg { width: 50px }`.

Comment: Without CSS, pure HTML view please.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can scale SVGs using the `width` and `height` HTML attributes like this:

```
<svg width="50" height="25">
```

SVG also provides a number of other attributes like `viewbox` and `preserveAspectRatio` to help you manage size, position, and scale. Check out [this article on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/) for more info.